# Android-To pass data to a specific row in list from an intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a list with rows containing two buttons. Button A in Row X click leads to launch of new activity.This new activity after achieving some conditions will show an alert box.
Clicking of yes in the Alert box must make those changes that are made when we click on Button B in the Row X.How can I implement it?.If I am using Intent then how can I make the values to pass to the Row x?? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the new activity (Activity B) from Activity A using

```
startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
```

In the intent pass the row x id.
Activity A -- (startActivityForResult(...)--> Activity B

Once the parent activity exits following method gets called.

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Activity B --  onActivityResult( Intent ) --> Activity A

You can pass the result along with row x's row id to Activity A in the intent.

Comment: @ Rajdeep Dua Sorry i didn't get you.